# Logger-annotation for ArrayList

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have several services:

```
@Service
public class Order {...}

@Service
public class Statistic {...}

@Service
public class Product {...}
```

All services are combined in a common class in ArrayLists

```
public class MyExample {

@MyLogAnnotation
private List <Order> listOrder;
@MyLogAnnotation
private List <Statistic> listStatistic;
@MyLogAnnotation
private List <Product> listProduct
}
```

How to implement the annotation(@MyLogAnnotation) that monitors Lists(Order,Statistic,Product) and every time a new service is added to the list. The logger displays the number of elements in the list and the class of a new service.

Comment: why do you have a List of Orders, if Order is a Service? Your design makes little to no sense at all. I would recommend first rethinking the design

Comment: Like @Stultuske said, lists of services (i.e. singletons!) do not make a lot of sense. Furthermore, Spring AOP usually works with annotations on classes or methods, not on fields. Last but not least, Spring AOP only works for Spring beans. JDK classes are no Spring components. Lots of design problems here. This is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). Please show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally on GitHub, and explain **what** you want to achieve, not **how** you believe it should be done technically. I am sure there is a good solution.

Comment: Hi Kriegaex! Thank you for the extended answer. Please see my repository. There I described my task in more detail. [link] https://github.com/finproject/aspect.git

Answer (score -1):

You will find something similar to what you're looking for [here](https://farenda.com/java/java-find-annotated-classes/). In addition to this, you can further use Reflection API to call size() method on your ArrayList(s).

Comment: Not quite. I need a dynamic solution that is executed every time the add () method of ArrayList is called. I am guessing that I need to write an aspect interceptor for  add () method or a custom lisener on tech spring